# When is it more logical to use Set as compared to Map?

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, set

For example I have a bunch of objects, say Cars. I need to keep track of a fleet of cars in the company. Obviously, cars are unique (VIN number), so they can be formed into a Set.

But I need everyday to change the state of some cars in the fleet, say to fill them with gas.

Which construct now makes sense? Why?

1. A dictionary with the VIN number as key and Car instance as value.
2. A Set of cars and then match on the Car.vin attribute.

Comment: You can use a set if the (immutable) VIN is the only thing that is used by `Car.__hash__`. However, if you need to access a `Car` by VIN, a set won't help you; sets don't support the notion of getting direct access to specific elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that things that both sets and maps/dicts work using hashes. **Hashed elements need to be immutable and preferably small** (faster hash calculation).

In your case, we don't know what is in the car instance and whether it changes. Maybe you can replace some parts or change the owner? If those are stored inside the instance, the car will have to be mutable.

So the obvious choice for the hash will be to go for a short VIN number that doesn't change. -> You should use a map (dict).

+In Python classes are by default mutable, so it's just easier to use some kind of (alpha)numerical id or a pair (tuple) of such elements.

Answer (score 1):

from what I can see keeping the data in a dictionary is a more suitable approach

if you have to change the state of your Car objects this means you have to search for that car (by the `VIN number`) and a dict can do this job in O(1) time complexity, I do not see how you can search by the `VIN number` for a Car object in a set (you can't)